# X11 GUI low quality display when using server

Tags: osx, fonts, display, server, x11

Why is Emacs X11's display such bad quality, and how do I fix it?

When I use Emacs Cocoa locally, I get a good visuals.  But when I use the X11 forwarding on my department's server, the quality is horrendous.  How do I fix the X11 version?

I'm doing this all on Mac OSX (El Capitan).  Here are some screenshots of the difference between the local, cocoa version and the X11 version:

Emacs Cocoa locally:
[image: cocoa]

Emacs X11 server version:
[image: X11]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that X defaults to a font that looks bad, or at least just has bad size. Try customizing fonts to make them look good (Options > Set Default font... from menu bar.)

You add something like this in your config file to change fonts only when you're using X:

```
(when (eq window-system 'x)
  ;; your custom font settings here
  )
```

Comment: Is there a way to find out what the default for my cocoa browser is, so that I can just copy those settings?

Comment: You can just take a look at what the font is set to in Cocoa, but I don't think that X will come with the same fonts. You're better off with just looking for something that looks similar.